# Flex TextInput has become uneditable

Tags: apache-flex, textinput

I have been developing an application for the past couple of weeks and as of yesterday all of the textinputs have become uneditable.  It seems like when you click on one it switches between the focusIn state and then back to the focusOut state.  What could cause this?

Comment: There are thousands of lines of code.  This does not just happen in one particular area, but shows up where ever the textinput control is.  Showing code would not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TabNavigator was causing the problem.  By removing the TabNavigator and replacing it with a TabBar and ViewStack it fixed the problem.  If you looking at the comments section of this page http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=navigators_4.html you will be able to see in more detail what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've added an event listener that causes you to lose focus just when you gain it. Without a look at the code, though, all we can do is guess.